# Compute $\mathbb{E}(T_y \ | \ T_y < \infty)$ for non-symmetric simple random walk

Tags: probability

Let $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$ be a non-symmetric simple random walk with $S_0 = 0$. For $y>0$ define 
$$
T_y = \min \lbrace n \geq 1 \ : \ S_n = y \rbrace
$$
How can I compute in a closed form the value of $\mathbb{E}(T_y \ | \ T_y < \infty)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $H_m$ be the hitting time of $\{-m, y\}$ ($m> 0$).  Do you know how to compute $\mathbb{E}[H_m\mid S_{H_m}=y]$?  Now let $m\to\infty$.